# Changeing Redirect HTML code to open in same window

Tags: javascript, html

How do I redirect a page to open in the same window instead of opening in a new tab. The code I currently have is:

```
window.location.href='discussion.html';
break;
}
```

Comment: window.location.append='discussion.html' ; seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
window.open(url,'_self')
```